# Get tarball from .tar.gz archive in gradle

Tags: gradle, gzip, tar, gunzip

I have some `.tar.gz`-Archives and would like to only unpack the Tarball to create a sha256-checksum hash of the `.tar`-File. (The reason for this is that the archive will be un- and repacked later on, as we are generating patch-files.)

Now this seems like an easy task but I'm stuck. There are either Gradle examples for:

1. getting the unpacked `tarTree` (with a Gradle Copy-Task and `tarTree(resources.gzip('model.tar.gz'))` (from documentation: [working with files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:archive_contents))
2. unzipping Files (with `zipTree`), which does not work with gzipped files

Both approaches do not work, since I need to create a checksum of the `.tar`-File itself. Unfortunately I can't use `commandLine` or `gunzip` as the tasks should run on both Windows and Linux.

The only solution I can imagine of right now is unpacking the `tar.gz` to a fileTree and repacking it to a tar-file, but I'm not even sure the checksum would be the same.

Is there really no way to do this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it to work with help from a colleague.

Using [`resources.gzip()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/resources/ResourceHandler.html#gzip-java.lang.Object-), which returns a `ReadableResource`, we can copy the resulting `InputStream` into a `.tar`-file with [IOUtils.copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)):

```
file("test.tar").withOutputStream { outputFile ->
    IOUtils.copy(resources.gzip(file("test.tgz")).read(), outputFile)
}
```

We also needed to add Apache commons (`"commons-io:commons-io:2.6"`) as a dependency.